# Singular or plural verb form

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number

I have problems with this sentence.

"Two week**s** off work sound**s** great or *sound* great". What form of the verb should I use in this case (and in similar sentences), if "weeks" is a plural noun?

Comment: It can be either. They are both correct. It depends on if you are considering two weeks to be a single block of time consisting of two weeks or if you are treating it as two units of time of a week each. Really, both the singular and plural are used in situations like this—because different people treat the noun phrase differently. It's similar to some people saying *your sixty minutes **start** now* [60 one-minute units of time] and other people saying *your sixty minutes **starts** now* [one 60-minute unit of time].

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your answer! I have found it both very interesting and beneficial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The verb should be "sounds," because the verb's subject should contain the implied gerund "taking," as in "Taking two weeks off work sounds great."

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying it. That's a massive help!